# Qubes OS does not see the laptop camera

Tags: linux, camera, qubes-os

Qubes Devices does not see the camera, only the microphone.
If I type lsusb the camera is visible:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 Root Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1358:c123 Realtek Bluetooth Radio
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:5110 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co, Ltd. Goodix fingerprint device 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:1040 Quanta Computer, Inc. ov9734_techfront_camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 3151:3020 YICHIP wireless device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 Root Hub
```

How to configure the camera please help.

Comment: Your question is [Off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in this part of the Matrix. Try it over there at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers for questions regarding programming. You might want to ask your question at [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).